# Cross browser compatibility web app bug trapping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I have a complex UI interface developed and working successfully on Firefox. It uses jQuery 1.8.+ and CSS2.

Now I need it to be compatible with the latest versions of Chrome and IE. Is there any solution that helps track *what* is wrong with the application in other browsers? I'm not asking for how it *looks* on another browser (I know there are many sites out there that help), but how it *works* and why things *don't* work on another browser. Basically I'm looking for the quickest problem tracker for any code on a browser. Because my otherwise useful application crashes significantly in Chrome and especially IE, and with so many plugins and thousands of LOC (and a deadline looming right ahead) I have no idea where to start debugging or seeing what's wrong.

Is there any manual technique or automatic tool that you know of that really helps out efficiently in this situation? If you have any personal techniques, please do share. One reason I don't know where to start is that if I use the developer mode in Chrome, it doesn't show any errors and yet doesn't work.

Comment: It would be useful if you expanded on "doesn't work"

Answer (score 3):

Probably not much of a help, but I remember two bizarre errors in IE. If you have two blocks of `document.ready()` somewhere, the latter one will be ignored, and thus the code won't run. The second one is related to declaring variables, which in some circumstances apparently will be ignored if 'var' prefix is omitted.

Additionally, IE has been reported to cause errors if DOCTYPE declaration was not specified, or there were white (or for that matter, any) characters before it.

Comment: thank you for the tips! i just discovered this second bizarre issue myself last night. i didn't know the first one but it'll probably be helpful now, since I'm still wading in all my code and trying to figure things out!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check each and every aspect of application, I prefer using [dynaTrace](http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/ajax-performance-testing.html). It works fine for me in IE and Mozilla.. In fact this is the favorite tool of John Resig according to one of his blog posts.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Firefox error console. That will report any JavaScript errors and the same errors affect Chrome as they are much the same, ie: Mozilla browsers. Not much you can do for IE except ensure that the code is free of error as run in Firefox.

Comment: are you referring to this? https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/error-console/

Comment: No. The Error Console has been standard issue since early Mozilla browsers. Look under Tools or Developer. They have moved it around over the years but it's still a JavaScript Debugger.